# Выполнение кода при подключении модуля

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте уважаемые!
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Например, есть у нас какая-то система фабрики классов. Требуется, что бы как только мы выполняем include какого-то такого класса, который должен быть в списке фабрики, он себя регистрирует в этой фабрике.

т.е. пусть фабрика - это статический массив указателей. Как только выполняем include модуль сам создаёт объект и добавляет его в этот лист. Как это можно сделать?

в pascale (Delphi) у модуля был такой прекрасный раздел как initialization. Вот нужно нечто вроде аналога. Желательно к стати и аналог, но вызываемый при отключении модуля (вызывается соответственно при завершении работы программы)

подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: include не имеет никакого отношения к модулям. Модули в С++ - совсем иное, нежели в других языках (Java, Python и т.п.). Здесь это - единица компиляции и больше ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. Во первых в c++ include подключается во время компиляции.

Можно написать код в cpp из которого подключаются include. Вот это чудо природы.

```
void RegisterInclude(char *name){
// код подключения
printf("Included: %s\r\n", name);
}

class RegisterIncludeClass{ public: RegisterIncludeClass(char *name){ RegisterInclude(name); } };

#define RESISTER_INCLUDE(name) RegisterIncludeClass name##name(#name);
```

А в инклудах добавить:

```
RESISTER_INCLUDE(имя_подключаемого_класса);
```

В итоге можно сохранить все подключенные модули в список и использовать по назначению. Главное не называть модули одинаково, иначе будет ошибка.
Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос :).

Comment: Я бы сказал, что директива #include является директивой препроцессора, т.е. работает еще до компиляции как таковой ))

Answer (score 1):

В С++ есть отдельно инклудники .h, которые указываются в #include и файлы с основным текстом .cpp или .cc .

Инклудники это не классы, они могут содержать что угодно, но обычно содержат декларации классов, может быть несколько в одном, определения же классов обычно помещают в .cpp

Само же подключение этих классов в программу производит компоновщик и на этом этапе ему совершенно не важно что у вас было написано в include, а важен набор уже скомпилированных объектных файлов. Одному исходному .cpp файлу соответствует один объектный файл, инклудники при этом вообще не учитываются, они включаются в текст файла .cpp препроцессором.

Теперь на счёт каких-то действий до старта main и после её (нормального) завершения. Это возможно с помощью любых внешних или статических переменных типа класс, у которого есть конструктор и деструктор. Конструкторы внешних переменных вызываются до старта main, деструкторы - после её завершения, но вот в каком порядке если их несколько - неизвестно.